# Is there a way to transform es6 vue file to es5 vue file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, babeljs

I used `async await` in my vue component, now I want to transform this file to es5.

I use rollup bundle this file, and `rollup-plugin-vue` can do this, finally I get a `.js` file, But I want a `.vue` file instead. Is there any way can do this?

this is my `rollup.config.js` file:

```
export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: {
            file: 'dist/index.js',
            format: 'iife',
            name: 'EXAM_COMPONENTS',
        },
        plugins: [
            vue(),
            resolve({
                browser: true,
            }),
            commonjs(),
            babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            }),
        ],
    },
]
```

In my `dist` directory, it's a `.js` file. but I wanna a es5 `vue` file. Can I do this?